# Loading big HTML file in c# web browser control on win form

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am developing a Windows Application using C# using .net 4.0 where in we have to show big HTML files in web control. The application works fine with the sizes up to 100 MB, but some time we need to load HTMLs upto 600 MB and in that cases the application hangs up and goes as not responding, though the configuration of the computers running this application is fine, it is C2D with 4 GB RAM.

Can some one help us to know how to handle such big HTML files loading in the web browser control in the win forms.

Thanks,
H N Mishra

Comment: What is in a HTML file that is 600 MB?

Comment: This sounds like extremely painful design.  I'd be concerned that there are some underlying architectural issues here.  I'd love to know as well what is taking up 600 MBs in your files

Comment: How often does HTML change ?

Comment: Do you loading HTML from the WWW or it's locally file ?

Comment: It is local files downloaded on our servers from Security and Exchange Commission, US. In fact these are html filings filed by Fund Issuers in US. We need to load these files in our applications to do some data capturing out of these files.

Answer (score 0):

A 600 MB DOM will just about kill any computer.  Modern browsers are certainly not up to that task without some lag.

You might look in to HTML Agility Pack as an alternative to loading the document in a browser.

Comment: What kind of tagging would be required? In fact, we did research but could not find any way. If could get some clue from you exerts. Thank in Advance!